# how to create sliding windows of differents size and sort

Tags: python, bash, awk

i'm working on some file consisting of interval (begin, end) and associated pattern.

exemple :

```
grep "HTT" dijen*.omim* | cut -f 2-4
begin       end         pattern
28557332    28557333    AAGAGGAGG
28557445    28557446    AAG
28557250    28557251    AAG
3076319 3076320 AGC
28542936    28542937    AGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
3052465 3052466 AC
3085084 3085085 AC
3051274 3051275 AC
3053094 3053095 AC
28556760    28556761    AAG
3051279 3051280 AC
3085521 3085522 AC
3084920 3084962 AC
3076453 3076454 AGC
3084794 3084795 AC
3076272 3076273 ACGCCCCCCGCATCGCC
3085257 3085258 AC
3140188 3140189 AAGG
3052498 3052499 AC
3053110 3053111 AC
3084759 3084760 AC
3053008 3053009 AC
3076570 3076571 AGGGGGGGCCGCGCCGGCGG
28557240    28557241    AAG
3052366 3052367 AC
3076334 3076335 AGC
3052487 3052944 AC
3084931 3084932 AC
3075962 3075963 AGGCGGGGCCGCGCCGGCGG
28557451    28557452    AAG
3052859 3052860 AC
3052446 3052447 AC
3076498 3076499 AGC
3139943 3139944 AACGAAGGAAGGAAGG
3052450 3052758 AC
3084985 3084986 AC
28556880    28556881    AAG
3052146 3052147 AC
3052923 3052924 AC
3084967 3084968 AC
3076275 3076281 AGC
3051420 3051421 AC
3076455 3076757 AGC

grep "HTT" dijen*.omim* | cut -f 2-4 | sort -u | wc -l
336
```

do you think there is a way ,with bash, to increment with +1 the begin and the end of each line at every step of the loop from 0 to 500 and count how many lines are still uniq and same by begin end pattern (or 80% of homology for begin and end)

something like :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import ipdb


gene_file = [line.strip() for line in open(sys.argv[1], "r")]
finale_liste = list()

def test_intervalle(liste):
    #test if 80% commun sequence between 2 intervals - if yes - merge the 2 intervals
    for i in liste:
        (begin_i, end_i, motif_i) = i
        for j in liste:
            (begin_j, end_j, motif_j) = j
            if (end_i-begin_j)/(end_i-begin_i) > 0.8 and motif_i == motif_j:
                liste.remove(i)
                liste.remove(j)
                liste.append([begin_i, end_j, motif_i])
    return(liste)
                


for i in range(1,501):
    output_name = "HTT_"+i+".txt"
    liste = list()
    for line in gene_file:
        (begin, end, motif) = line.split("\t")
        begin = int(begin)+i
        end = int(end)+i
        liste.append([begin, end, motif])
    
    new_liste = test_intervalle(liste)
    with open(output_name, 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\t")
        for i in new_liste:
            w.writerow(i+"\n")
    command_line = "sort -u "+ output_name+ "| wc -l"
    stream = os.popen(command_line)
    output = stream.read()
    finale_liste.append((i, output))

with open("finale_liste.txt", "w") as finale:
    for i in finale_liste:
        finale.write(i"\n")
```

something like that but in bash, or awk or better python ?

Comment: I guess the intervals are given by the 2 first columns you show. I also guess that the first column is the `min` end of the interval and the second is the `max` end. But I don't understand the concept of _slinding windows from 0 to 500 around the interval_ What are these windows for a `min max` interval?

Comment: yes you guessed correctly :)

Comment: let's take the first line : 28557332    28557333    AAGAGGAGG,this is for 0, nothing is add and i can count all the line exactly like this one. next step i will try to add+1, 28557332+1   28557333+    AAGAGGAGG, and see how many intervals can group into this new interval and count the number of uniq line by interval+1, and doing that to extend to +500, i don't know if it's more clear?

Comment: *I have tried with Python but it is not efficient for large files*. That is true, but Pandas is a very powerful addition for handling large datasets. My greater problem here is that I really could not understand what you wanted to do, so I cannot say whether it can be done using Pandas...

Comment: @SergeBallesta i edited my question, hope it's more clear now!

Comment: @MarineBergot It's a bit more clear but still not 100%. So, for each line `min max pat` of your file, and for each value `v` from 0 to 500 (that is, 501 different values), you would like to count the number of times you have **exactly** `min+v max+v pat` in the same input file? If you have one million lines this will produce 501 millions records, correct?

Comment: @MarineBergot And what is 80% of homology for begin and end?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yeah exactly, it can be huge indeed..  by 80% homology i mean, for two given interval if they are not exactly the same but if 80% of one interval in contained inside another, then this interval should be add like the same

Comment: You really should give the exact algo (including the *80% homology* point) that you want in any language or even pseudo-code, along with an example input data and the expected output. Without that it is really hard to help you

Comment: @SergeBallesta i updated with my python code - not perfect and didn't tested if for everything

Comment: We can't tell what you want to do by reading code that doesn't do what you want to do.

Comment: From your code, I can say that creating the records for 1 -> 500 will be easy with Pandas and numpy. The hard part is th *80% homology*. Your current code does not meet the requirement at all (and tries to alter the list being iterated which gives undefined results...) but it is not really trivial... at least in an efficient way...

Comment: I could make some tests using Pandas and numpy, but I cannot guess whether the results are correct. Could you provide an example input and output?

Comment: Many of the intervals are only 1 long (n, n+1), yet the patterns are more than one letter long.

Comment: Could there be a typo in `(end_i-begin_j)/(end_i-begin_i)`?  `i` occurs 3 times, `j` once.